# GAM : choosing the a function for each predictor

Tags: r, glmnet, generalized-additive-model, statistical-learning

When using GAM methods for prediction:

$y = af_1(x1) + bf_2(x2) + cf_3(x3)...
$

Where $x_1,x_2.. $ are predictors / features used in the data. The gam package in R helps us find the best functions and the coefficients.

This is what I wish to achieve:

$y = af_1(x1) + bf_2(x2) + cf_3(x3)...$

where $f_1(x_1)$ maybe $\log$ or sine/cosine / exponent etc., I want to be able to explore more functions in GAM other than just splines. Also the ability for each predictor to have a different function like $f_1(x_1)$ maybe $\log$ and $f_2(x_2)$ maybe sine -- meaning the user does not have to predefine the function.

Is there a package which does this? or If I've to write one, what method do I pursue to determine the best function for each predictor such that a linear combination of those will help reduce the RMSE for the prediction.

Comment: There are no coefficients in front of the functions $\{ f_i \}_{i=1}^{p}$ since any constant is considered part of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a package that does this. In fact, I would be surprised in this exists; this is actually much simpler than what a GAM does. All you need to do is transform your covariates (as apposed to expanding the support basis as a GAM does) with the transformation that you like and fit a simple linear model with the transforme covariates (or maybe glm). If you really wanted, you could quickly write a script that fits several models, each with your transformations of interest and perhaps choices the model with the highest likelihood (comparing AIC's would be equivalent to comparing likelihoods, as the degrees of freedom would not change).

I wouldn't really advise this though. It sounds like your motivation is that you are unsure about the functional form of your covariates, and that this would be a method of choosing them. However, it's really hard to think why the functional form should be a very specific function of the choices provided *even though we apparently don't know which function in advance*. Keep in mind that splines are popular *because* they provide very good approximations of most smooth functions. Thus, you can take advantage of the fact that you expect the functional form to be smooth, without having to specify exactly what that function is.

I hope I'm not being too mean, but to me it seems like the only scenario where this would out perform a GAM is if someone told you "I've generated data and I've used either a quadratic, square root, exponential or logarithmic transformation of the covariates, but definitely not anything else. Build a predictive model".

Comment: Okay I get your point that splines are awesome for estimating smooth functions. So this is an engineering problem, where estimating a function for a given covariate would help a huge deal in inferences. The inference drawn from the function which fits the covariance the best is important to an engineer. The function would be trying to explain how the predictor influences the physical phenomena being modeled.

Comment: On this same point, in the case of random forests for example, randomly dropping a few predictors and building a tree with a subset of the same helps in increasing the accuracy of prediction. Would the same apply if used in GAM? Choosing a random subset of the predictors and generating a predictive GAM based off that, then averaging all the models.